# Clone a real server to a VPS

Tags: linux, redhat, vps, dd, rackspace-cloud

I have an old server ( Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES release 2.1 (Panama) ) that is in desperate need of replacing, is it possible using dd / ssh to clone the server onto a Rackspace VPS? Or more precisely after the server is cloned what problems can I expect e.g. booting etc?

I have successfully used this command (found in another serverfault question) to clone one vps to another:

```
dd if=/dev/sda | gzip | ssh root@target 'gzip -d | dd of=/dev/sda'
```

but that was two machines of the spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux is largely ok with this, so it might work. *HOWEVER* It is possible that you need special drivers for the vps to operate correctly. Can you install and run any OS on the VM? If so, then it's probably possible to do. It'll be better if you can boot both systems from a LiveCD image to do the copy.